# why do (( cout << ptr; cout << "\n" << ++ptr; )) and (( cout << ptr << "\n" << ++ptr; )) give different results

Tags: c++, pointers, cout

I'm new to c++ and I have recently spent a couple of days reading about pointers.I realized that the 2 following codes give me different results although they seem identical.

the first code:

```
int a = 5;
int* ptr = &a;
cout << ptr;
cout << "\n" << ++ptr;
```

the second code:

```
int a = 5;
int* ptr = &a;
cout << ptr << "\n" << ++ptr;
```

here is the output of the first one:

> 0043F940
>   0043F944

the output of the second one:

> 003AFE20
>   003AFE20

the first one seems more logical to me since it first outputs the address of `a` and then the address of the next integer location.But in the second one `ptr` is apparently always pointing to `a`.
Can someone explain this difference to me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The second code snippet has undefined behavior because the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.

Comment: "*But in the second one ptr is apparently always pointing to a.*" How did you determine that? Isn't it much more likely that you've just output the incremented value twice?

Comment: As @VladfromMoscow pointed out, the order is undefined. Thus, `++ptr` gets evaluated first and then `ptr` again, with the same value. They likely don't point to `a`, but to the next location. You could verify this with `cout << &a`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: No longer in C++17 (which OP doesn't use), see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: Reopened. The alleged duplicate had nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your comments and answers. I didn't notice that it was related to evaluation sequence and that was why I couldn't find any answer over the web and i thought that might be a visual studio bug.Thanks for taking your time to answer and sorry it was somehow duplicate :)

Answer (score 2):

Look closely at: `cout << ptr << "\n" << ++ptr;`

Your code is like `f (ptr, ++ptr);` which has the same issue.

Both lines of code have two places where the value of `ptr` is read and one place where the value of `ptr` is written. While the read in `++ptr` has to take place before the write, the read of `ptr` (for `<< ptr` or the first parameter to `f`) has no restrictions on when it takes place and can take place either before or after the write.

This is because C++ does not specify the order in which a function's parameters are evaluated. Apparently, on your platform, with your compiler flags, the increment happens to take place before the other read. So you output the incremented value twice.

Comment: Notice that C++17 imposes eval order for `E1 << E2`.

Answer (score 1):

Let us name the [`operator<<(a, b)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) now as function `f(a, b)`. 
Using this notation `cout << 5` becomes `f(cout, 5)`. Using the fact that the `<<` operator has left-to-right associativity, `cout << 4 << "a"` becomes `f(f(cout, 4), "a")`.

Let's translate your code:

```
cout << ptr << "\n" << ++ptr;
```

to:

```
f(f(f(cout, ptr), "\n"), ++ptr);
```

As you can see, the most outer call to `f` has as second argument `++ptr`. Since C++ doesn't specify the order of evaluation of arguments to a function call, it is free to increment `ptr` first, before evaluating the nested `f(...)` function call.

Comment: Notice that C++17 imposes eval order for `E1 << E2`.